React Native stuck on :app:createBundleDevelopmentDebugJsAndAssets during build process
I'm working on a React Native project and running into an issue where the build process gets stuck at the :app:createBundleDevelopmentDebugJsAndAssets task. Here are the details:

React Native Version: 0.74
Android Gradle Plugin: 8.2.1
Gradle Version: 8.6
Metro Version: v0.80.10
Environment: I'm running the build using yarn android:debug:dev.

The build process gets stuck at 9% and doesn't progress further, even after several hours. Here is a snippet of the output log:
yarn android:debug:dev

yarn run v1.22.22
$ cp .env.Development .env && cp .config.Development .config && react-native run-android --mode=DevelopmentDebug --appIdSuffix=dev --active-arch-only
(node:15764) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Detected architectures x86_64
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.2.1
Gradle: 8.6

> Task :app:createBundleDevelopmentDebugJsAndAssets
debug Reading Metro config
warning: the transform cache was reset.
                Welcome to Metro v0.80.10
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated


tailwindcss(native) rebuilding... done
<=------------> 9% EXECUTING [3h 21m 21s]
> :app:createBundleDevelopmentDebugJsAndAssets
> IDLE

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? What might be causing the build process to hang at this stage, and how can I resolve it?
I've tried the following:

Resetting the Metro cache with yarn start -- --reset-cache.
Reinstalling node_modules and clearing other related caches.
Ensuring that all dependencies are up to date.

Despite these efforts, the build remains stuck at 9%. The only significant warnings I'm seeing are related to deprecated modules (punycode).
